# Assign an additional value to hash in perl

Tags: perl

(...New to perl)

I have a hash that is setting something like this below. I want it to store extra value but its failing without throwing any error.

```
execute(\%values);


sub execute()
{
   my ($values) = @_;
   my $areacode = "982222";
   my $name = "john";

   $values->{"area"}{$areacode}{person}{$name}= 1;

   my $hashid = "123456";
   $values->{"area"}{$areacode}{person}{$name}{id}= $hashid;
}
```

After this, if I

```
print $values->{"area"}{$areacode}{person}{$name}{id};
```

I dont see anything and script fails.
How do I make hash store this extra value?

When do I use `""` for fields like area?

Comment: All variables are prefixed using a `$`. You've got `person` and `name` with no `$` prefix. Are they literals or are they variables?

Comment: That was a typo. I already fixed it. Please refresh.

Comment: person is literal. Should it be included in quotes. I don't see it used that way in my code, though. Only area is in quotes.

Comment: Sooo... put it in quotes. Did you inherit this from someone? What's this hash supposed to store? Usually hashes are key->value pairs. This appears to be some sort of multi-dimensional implementation...

Comment: @RyanJ: No, a bareword between `{}` doesn't need quotes; `$values->{area}{$areacode}{person}{$name} = 1;` is perfectly legal and idiomatic.

Comment: Well, the OP's use of `my` implies the use of `strict`, and if it doesn't, it should. In which case, that wouldn't be allowed. My opinion isn't relevant to this thread though, so I will leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks. I did add use strict. And it gave me the error. Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at t

Comment: @user3606175 You should always use `use strict; use warnings;` to avoid making these kind of hard to diagnose mistakes. If you do not use them, your errors do not go away, they just stay hidden.

Comment: @RyanJ: Even with `use strict;`, barewords between `{}` don't need to be quoted. There may be other problems with the code; I haven't studied it closely. (If you want to reply to a comment, please include the user's name preceded by `@`, so the use will be notified.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the

```
$values->{area}{$areacode}{person}{$name} = 1;
```

you assign to the `...{$name}` number `1`. In the next step,

```
$values->{"area"}{$areacode}{person}{$name}{id}= $hashid;
#-----------------------------------^^^^^^^ <--hashref
```

want use this number `1` as an `hashref` - what is ofcourse wrong.

Use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Also you can use the `Data::Dumper` for dump your data structure, so the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
execute(\%hash);
print Dumper \%hash;

sub execute {
    my ($values) = @_;
    my $areacode = "982222";
    my $name = "john";

    $values->{area}{$areacode}{person}{$name}{num} = 1;
    # ----------------------------------------^^^ some key

    my $hashid = "123456";
    $values->{area}{$areacode}{person}{$name}{id} = $hashid;

    #adding another
    $values->{area}{$areacode}{person}{joe}{num} = 2;
    $values->{area}{$areacode}{person}{joe}{id} = $hashid;

    $values->{area}{'0000000'}{person}{susan}{num} = 1;
    $values->{area}{'0000000'}{person}{susan}{id} = 10000;
}
```

Note the quoted `0000000` - without quotes it would be interpreted as number `0`.

prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'area' => {
                      '0000000' => {
                                     'person' => {
                                                   'susan' => {
                                                                'id' => 10000,
                                                                'num' => 1
                                                              }
                                                 }
                                   },
                      '982222' => {
                                    'person' => {
                                                  'joe' => {
                                                             'id' => '123456',
                                                             'num' => 2
                                                           },
                                                  'john' => {
                                                              'id' => '123456',
                                                              'num' => 1
                                                            }
                                                }
                                  }
                    }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks. This is making sense now. But, How do I add this extra value to this hash? Do I need a new hash that stores this?

Comment: Thanks. I needed to set {id} for {name}, so I ended up working the datastructure to store that details. So, I didn't use this solution, but this helped me get on track. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
$values->{"area"}{$areacode}{person}{$name}= 1;

my $hashid = "123456";
$values->{"area"}{$areacode}{person}{$name}{id}= $hashid;
```

you are trying to make `$values->{"area"}{$areacode}{person}{$name}` have both number and a hash reference as a value; you can't do that.

Comment: Thankss. Makes sense. How do I solve this then? Use a new datastructure?

Comment: depends *why* you wanted the value for the key $name to be both 1 and a hash.